# Some cells in formatted date column appearing in mm-dd-yyyy while rest are dd-mm-yyyy

Tags: excel, vba, date

I have a file where I need to check if the current week falls within the specified dates for each record. The dates, named Effective and Expiry dates are in columns E and F. Since the file is downloaded from some database, I have done some level of cleaning on the columns. (Note: "current" week is always the previous week)

This is my code:

```
Public Sub datechk()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i, cnt As Long
Dim temp As String
Dim current_Sun, current_Mon As Date
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet

current_Mon = Date - Weekday(Date, vbMonday) + 1 - 7
current_Sun = Date - Weekday(Date, vbSunday) + 1

ws.Range("C1").CurrentRegion.Replace What:="null", Replacement:="", _
        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False
cnt = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.Range("C:C"))
'short date format
    For i = 2 To cnt
        temp = ws.Cells(i, "E").Value
        On Error Resume Next
        ws.Cells(i, "E").Value = Mid(temp, 1, InStr(temp, " ") - 1)
        temp = ws.Cells(i, "F").Value
        On Error Resume Next
        ws.Cells(i, "F").Value = Mid(temp, 1, InStr(temp, " ") - 1)
    Next
    On Error GoTo 0
    ws.Range("E:F").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
For i = 2 To cnt
        If current_Sun <= ws.Cells(i, "E").Value Or current_Mon >= ws.Cells(i, "F").Value Then
            ws.Cells(i, "G").Value = 0
        Else
            ws.Cells(i, "G").Value = 1
        End If
        If IsEmpty(ws.Cells(i, "F")) Or ws.Cells(i, "F").Value = 0 Or ws.Cells(i, "F").Value = "" Then
            ws.Cells(i, "G").Value = 1
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Columns E and F contain the effective and expiry dates. Column G is my checker for whether my current week falls within the date range.

Now this works perfectly fine on my laptop. However, when my client ran the code, he was getting an error. Certain cells in the expiry date(F) column was appearing in (mm-dd-yyyy) format and hence throwing off the checker.

Eg:
Where the expiry date was 01-10-2020, in my client's output file, it was showing as 10-01-2020.

This was not happening in every row and this was not happening with effective date(E). I have checked the output file my client has and the formatting on that particular cell is still dd-mm-yyyy.

Would someone happen to know why this is happening and how it could be fixed? Since I am not getting this error when I run the code myself, I am unable to try and fix it too.

(This is my first time posting. Please let me know if more info is needed)

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your client probably has a different Region setting (look in Windows / Settings / Time & Language / Region). If you have Regional Format set to English (United Kingdom), and he/she has English (United States) then you will get dd/mm as default in Excel (which picks up the Windows settings) and your client will get mm/dd. Welcome to the wonderful world of programming with dates!

One way to get around this might be to use the VALUE() function in Excel to convert the string representation of the date to an Excel Date variable. Eg =VALUE("12-Jun-20") returns 43994 (the number of days since 1-Jan-1900). If you have the dd/mm regional setup, =VALUE("12/06/2020") will give 43994. If your client has the mm/dd setting then =VALUE("06/12/2020") will also return 43994. Then you can use this variable in your code.

(Also, I prefer using Int(Now()), to get today's date, rather than the Date statement, as this is also a datatype which could lead to confusion)